# How to refine image with rough horizontal lines using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have this kind of image that has rough horizontal lines and I want to remove it or at least make those lines not really visible.

[image]

Using smoothing technique such as Gaussian Blur, I couldn't get satisfying result as the lines still visible and it just make resolution of the image lower.

```
cv::GaussianBlur(image, result, cv::Size(5, 5), 3);
```

[image]

Is there any other method that is more suitable for my problem? Thank you

Comment: Do we talk about hte horizontal lines or the diagonol ones? If the diagonal ones are thin they might disappear after median filter. The horizontal lines: You would have to blur more, maybe only in vertical direction.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy the horizontal line, I will edit my question, thanks. How to blur only in vertical direction?

Comment: @gameon67 You can modify the kernel size, e.g. use `cv::GaussianBlur(image, result, cv::Size(1, 15), 0)`. Here, blurring in `x` direction is omitted, and blurring in `y` direction is increased. I guess, that's what the other commentator wanted to suggest.

Comment: Use a horizontal edges detector and divide your image by the edge image. This will weaken the horizontal lines of the image. (You can multiply a constant value to the result image to make it better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @gameon67 suggested you can use kernel size of 1x15 to increase blurring in y direction and omitting in x direction. However, I feel for this case Average filtering is better suited than Gaussian filtering. You can read more about them in the official [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html).

```
img = cv2.blur(img,(1, 15)) # average filtering
```

[image: average filtering result]

```
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (1, 15), 0) # Gaussian filtering
```

[image: gaussian filtering result]

Comment: I've tried it and average blur is better for this case. Thank you!